# ¿Existe alguna forma de pasar datos entre links?

Tags: javascript, html, http, redirección

Quiero hacer una pagina de `redireccionando.html` pero tengo varios links en el `índex.html` y no quiero tener que hacer un `redireccionando_link_1.html`, `redireccionando_link_2.html`, etc.

Es posible que solo tenga que hacer **una** pagina de redireccionando en vez de una por cada link distinto que tenga mi pagina?

O sea, que llame a `redireccionando.html` con un parámetro que sea el link al que se le dio click.

## Resuelto:

Al `redireccionando.html` le agregué el siguiente <*script*>

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var url = location.href;
  var arr_url=url.split("?");
  var arr_var =arr_url[1].split("=");
  var pagina= arr_var[1];

  function redireccionar(){
    location.href=pagina
  } 

  setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 1000);
</script>
```

La pagina se llama usando el siguiente formato: `http://www.yoyomero.com/redirecting.html?next=http://www.google.com`

Donde `http://www.yoyomero.com/redirecting.html` es la pagina

Y `?next=http://www.google.com` es a donde se quiere ir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer desde el JavaScript también

```
    var url= location.href;// Guardamos la  url actual
    var arr_url=url.split("?");// cortamos la url
    /*Esta función corta la url. Si la url es 
      "ejemplo.com/redirect?next=ejemplo.com" quedaría un arreglo
      ["ejemplo.com/redirect","next=ejemplo.com"] */
```

Fíjate que el signo "?" es el delimitador. Esta función corta una cadena donde encuentre el delimitador que le pasamos por parámetro.
Más información sobre esta función.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp.

```
     //Accedemos al segundo elemento del arreglo "arr_url"
     var arr_var =arr_url[1].split("=");
     //Solo si  tienes solo una variable 
     // si tienes más variables debes usar el delimitador "&" para cortar 
     var next_url= arr_var[1];

     location.href=next_url;
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, lastima que no tengo 15 reputación para darte una flecha arriba.

Comment: Bueno, oye, una vez que tengo el link en la variable next_url como la pago al html para que `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=https://www.link.com/next_url"> ` tenga el link de next_url?

Comment: Bueno, oye, una vez que tengo el link en la variable next_url como la paso al html para que `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=https://www.link.com/next_url"> ` tenga el link de next_url? (Ese es el meta que hacer que después de 1 segundo redireccione la pagina al link indicado)

Comment: Es código Javascript , no lo puedes colocar en  la etiqueta meta. Abres en el HTML las etiquetas <script> y pones el código allí. La instrucción "location.href" devuelve la url actual y con "location.href=acá_la_página" redireccionamos. Puedes también como dije hacer la redirección desde el servidor.

Comment: Si quieres redireccionar después de 1 segundo usa la función "SetTimeout();" entonces: SetTimeout(function_a_ejecutar, 1000); el número 1000 significa un segundo porque se expresa en milisegundos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, arriba dejo la edición de Resuelto

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta va directo a como hacer la redireccion: Todo depende de como quieras que se comporte pues hay 2 opciones:

1- Que la pagina de re-dirección quede en el historial del browser, lo que haría difícil (por no decir casi imposible) volver hacia atrás la navegación usando el botón "back" del navegador, pero hay casos donde se quiere que funcione asi por lo que te dejo un ejemplo...

En este caso usa algo así en el `<head>` de `redireccionando.html`:

```
<script>
  window.location.href = window.location.search.substring(1);
</script>
```

2- Que la pagina de re-dirección no quede en el histrial del browser, lo que hace que funcione similar a Google cuando clickeas en una búsqueda, que primero va a una pagina intermedia que te redirecciona a la pagina que clickaste en primer lugar.

En este caso usa algo así en el `<head>` de `redireccionando.html`:

```
<script>
  window.location.replace(window.location.search.substring(1));
</script>
```

### Espera...

Ambos métodos requieren que invoques la pagina de esta forma

```
redireccionando.html?http%3A%2F%2Fotrositio.com%2Fotra_pagina.html
```

Donde la dirección del otro sitio a donde redireccionas se encuentra URL encodeada. Hay varias formas de encodear la URL en primer lugar. Si quieres puedes usar php en tu `index.html`... podrías hacerlo así: (use un ejemplo del repositorio que linkeaste en la pregunta)

```
<a href="redireccionando.html?<?=urlencode("https://www.facebook.com/yoyomerotienda/posts/1802148900025449")?>" title="D1 GHZ - Azul" target="_blank">
   <img alt="D1 GHZ Azul" src="http://yoyomero.com/eCommerceAssets/images/stuff/Loop/200x200.jpg">
</a>
```

Salu2

Comment: Gracias, ahora mismo estoy haciendo la pagina de redireccionando. Luego aplico lo que me dices para ver si me surge alguna duda :)

Comment: Oye, si pongo el metodo que al final me diste con la url de Facebook, puedo hacer que la pagina de redireccionando se ve un rato? O por defecto ya se verá?

Comment: para hacer que se vea un rato, tendrias que poner un "delay" antes de hacer modificar `window.location`. podrias envolver ese metodo dentro de un bloque `setTimetout`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, arriba dejo la edición de Resuelto

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir variables de tipo `GET` a tu url para ver a donde redireccionar, incluso hay una común que es llamada `next`, se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
http://yoursite.com/?next=redireccionando_link_1.html
```

Donde `?` le dice a la url que hay habrá una variable, `next` seria el nombre de la variable, y lo que está luego del `=` es el valor de la variable, notase que así como puede llamarse `next` tambien puedes poner `redirect` o lo que quieras.

Ya lo que queda es desde tu servidor que no sé en que lenguaje lo estas programando, recuperar la variable y decidir a donde redireccionar de acuerdo al valor de dicha variable.

Comment: Mi servidor solo tiene por el momento un índex.html.

Comment: Pero, ¿Sabes en que lenguaje de programación está corriendo el servidor?, puedes mostrarme como estás redireccionando actualmente?

Comment: Si quieres echar un vistazo al [GitHub](https://github.com/J053Fabi0/Yoyomero_2nd_page).

Comment: Pero creo que es PHP porque es hostinger

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, arriba dejo la edición de Resuelto